# Is there any scroll options available for appium other than scrollto and scrolltoExact?

Tags: java, android, appium

Is there any scroll options available for appium other than scrollto and scrolltoExact? For Example: like Scroll up, scroll down, Scroll to next, Scroll to next Screen/Page, Scroll to end, Scroll to Home. Please let me know if there are any other scroll options.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, you can use TouchAction class to perform scrolling. Look [here](http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html)